# How can I increase dijit toolbar icon size?

Tags: toolbar, dojo

In dijit toolbar the default icon size is 16x16 px
I would like to make a toolbar with icons with size 20x20 (or bigger so it will be more comfortable for user).

I've created new icons and added them to the CSS but I'm not sure how to re size the toolbar itself to show 20x20 icons.

Here is example how I create toolbar today:
http://jsfiddle.net/D4BVT/

```
 <div id="toolbar1" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" style="background-color:inherit;background-image:none;border-bottom:0px;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.cut" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'PanIcon', showLabel:false">Cut</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.copy" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy', showLabel:false">Copy</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.paste" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste', showLabel:false">Paste</div>
            <!-- The following adds a line between toolbar sections-->
            <span data-dojo-type="dijit/ToolbarSeparator"></span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id="toolbar1.bold" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconBold', showLabel:false">Bold</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default icons are only 16px (height of them is 18px in CSS), if you want to use bigger icons, then you will have to create custom icon classes in CSS with these bigger icons.

For example:

```css
.customCutIcon {
    background-image: url("http://url.to/your/cut-icon.png");
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

And then you can use that as your `iconClass` in your `data-dojo-props`. The toolbar will automatically adapt to this new height. I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/N8PWp/). I used colors in this example, but you can also use icons.

Comment: Thank you.
It didnt work when I tried and now worked with your example. :)